# ASP.NET Session in different domains

Tags: asp.net, session, cross-domain

I open a link using `window.open('http://www.OthersSite1.co.in/')` with some parameters from my main site(say MySite1)

where I have no control over the OthersSite1 and it is in another domain, but have full control on MySite1.

The issues is I loss `Session` of MySite1 even if I close the opened window of OthersSite1.

How does this happen? 
I tried with window.open('http://stackoverflow.com'), it works well.

Any thoughts ...?

Comment: Hi.. Can u just check this once http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/114484/Single-Sign-On-SSO-for-cross-domain-ASP-NET-applic

Comment: how do you detect that you have lost the ASP.NET session?

Comment: @Davide Piras When I click some buttons on 'MySite1' after closing the window, it redirects to log in page :(

Comment: redirect to login page indicates that your auth cookie expired, and not the session cookie. how much time does it pass between opening the window and realizing that the session is lost? Those cookies are set to expire within 20/30 minutes by default; if you want to maintain the login session, you may need to write some client/js script to keep it alive. Also, I would suggest opening the 2nd site using a method such as: `<a href="second site" target="_blank">open second site</a>`. This will open it in another window or tab (depending on browser settings), eliminating probs with popup blockers.